# Laravel Ecommerce Database Design

Tags: database, laravel

I started an Ecommerce with a lot of different products and my Database Schema look like this actualy, i would like to know if this schema will be good to create products with attributes and some without.

If a product don't have attributes i still can store the stock info and price.

If someone have another idea it will more than welcome.

```
categories
-id
-name

products
-id
-nom
-description
-category_id

products_attributs
-id
-product_id
-name (ex : size, color .. )

product_attribut_options
-id
-product_id
-product_attribut_id
-name (ex : XL, bleu .. )

stock
-id
-product_id
-price
-quantity_available

stock_values
-id
-product_id
-product_attribute_id
-product_attribute_option_id
-stock_id
```

Comment: There are several ways you can do it. For a simple app, your design looks right. Although you can use less. For example, if you setup relationships right, you don't need `product_attribute_id` or `product_attribute_option_id` in `stock_values` table. You can simply call them through `product`

Comment: yes i agree i can remove it from this table. For a complex app this will be not enought ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. From this tables, it looks like you want a simple stock app with product list with some product attributes. For complex app, setting relation correctly is more important

Comment: thanks for the info i apprecied a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stock_values, you may change the column product_attribute_id to product_attribut_options_id (this column should be null in case not have attributes) considering the product always have prices.

Comment: Yes you are right ig the product don't have attribut this column will be null. Si you think i need to remove product_attribut_id from stock_values ? maybe i don't have to store yes because i can access to product_attribut_option to get the attributes infos

Comment: yes, because the product_attribute_option table already have the product_attribut_option_id

Comment: in the model of the product_attribute_option you must put the relationship return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductAttribuct','product_attribut_id'); in order to get the product_attribuct throught product_attribut_option

Comment: with this schema there is any problem if a product have many attributes right ?

Comment: in each stock_values you must put or not put the product_attribute_option_id, in order to know the product_attribute_option_id for this price

Comment: but if you want to count the quantity of the product_attribute_option you must use the relationship